# Arduino + sim800l + dht11

Tags: arduino, sim800l

I am trying to make a call only once. But it is calling over and over.
Code is
If(t>20){
Sim800l.println(ATD +phone number)}
How can I make it to call me once only? I just need to inform me if temperature is over 20°C. Using dht11, arduino uno and sim800l.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flag like so. Everytime the temperature drops below/equal to 20 the flag `hasChanged` will be set to `true`. And when the temperature rises above 20, the message will be printed once, and the flag will be toggled off until the next time the temperature drops.

```
// you'll have to adjust the syntax to meet your language needs

bool hasChanged = true;
if (t>20 && hasChanged) {
   // this block happens once everytime the temperature surpasses 20
   Sim800l.println(ATD +phone number);
   hasChanged = false;
} else {
   hasChanged = true;
}
```